# exporting 23.98 fps as a png sequence in blender 2.8

Tags: frame-rate

I'm trying to export my animation in 23.98 fps as a png or openEXR sequence in blender 2.8 however when I import it to a composition software such as after effects it says that the sequence is at 30 fps. However, when I export an AVI file instead of a sequence format it exports as 23.98 fps.

Comment: Standalone image files have no concept of frame rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside After Effects you could right click on your image sequence and select  "interpret footage".

With that you can change the frame rate.

Hope that helps.

Good luck